# Strange popup behavior

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, matblazor

I have a modal popup controller that I dynamically render on the page defined as follows

```
<MatDialog @bind-IsOpen="@Open">
    <MatDialogTitle>@Title</MatDialogTitle>
    <MatDialogContent>
        @Content
    </MatDialogContent>
    <MatDialogActions>
        <MatButton OnClick="@Yes">Yes</MatButton>
        <MatButton OnClick="@(e => { Open = false; })">No</MatButton>
    </MatDialogActions>
</MatDialog>

@code {
    [Parameter] public bool Open { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public string Title { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public string Content { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<string> YesCallback { get; set; }


    void Yes()
    {
        Open = false;
        YesCallback.InvokeAsync("deleted");           
    }

}
```

It just meant to close the popup and call the passed in callback function. Issue is if `YesCallback.InvokeAsync("deleted");` is called dialog never closes. The callback gets executed but the dialog stays open. If `YesCallback.InvokeAsync("deleted");` is removed the dialog closes fine, but, obviously no callback is called.

There are no errors.

Comment: Your call back is probably wrongly used. In your previous question I have demonstrated how to create a call back and how to use it... please, show how you create your call back and the rest of the code...

Comment: `EventCallback.Factory.Create(this, Delete)` is how I create the call.